# Return intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent

Hey guys I'm not a very advanced programmer so i'm scratching my head at this weird issue I'm getting. Trying to make `Activity A` call `Activity B` so that it can add some data to a `SQL Database` and exit back into `Activity A`. The issue is `Button` on `Activity B` to return to `Activity A` is broken and won't even output any Android Monitor Logs.

**Activity A calls B using:**

```
private void btnFunc (){
    Button btnAddSubject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new_subject);
    btnAddSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddSubject.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,1);
        }
    });

}
```

This Is what **Activity B's** return Function looks like it is called in the onCreate function:

```
public void Continue(){
    //SQL Instances
    subject = new SQLSubject(this);
    mContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = subject.insertData(add_subject.getText().toString(),
                            add_subject_group.getText().toString(),
                            add_teacher.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddSubject.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        returnIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        setResult(1);
                        startActivity(returnIntent);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddSubject.this, "Error saving data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        returnIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        setResult(0);
                        startActivity(returnIntent);

                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The onCreate also includes:

```
finishActivity(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning an Intent, you are restarting the other activity (and doing nothing with the `returnIntent`).

You should set the intent in the result and finish the current activity.

For example

```
setResult(1, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Then the code for `onActivityResult` will be called in the activity that had `startActivityForResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`setResult(1);` and `setResult(0);`

call it as:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent); //instead of setResult(1);
```

and

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent); //instead of setResult(0);
```

Comment: That's just a constant, it doesn't really matter if the proper check is in `onActivityResult`

Comment: if its really like this then how [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/2715073) have more than 1000 votes.

Comment: Because it was clearly explained? `if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)` could just as easily be `if(resultCode == 0)`. It's **just a constant** as it stands , this is a suggestion, not a solution